# Shell Script for finding .txt, .csv files from folders/subfolder, recreate the source path folder on different path and copy the files

Tags: shell, scripting

Looking for Shell Script to find **'.txt', '.csv'** files from many recursive folders/subfolders, copy the files and recreate the same folders path to copy those files in new path.

Example:
we got around 20k files and saved in many parent folders and subfolders.

Source:
u01/temp/proj/sales/john/**.csv**, .xls files
u01/temp/proj/sales/mike/**.txt, .csv**, .xls files
u01/temp/proj/sales/geebee/sale/**.csv**, .xls files

need shell script to copy **only '.txt', '.csv'** files(exclude xls , other files) and recreate same folder path then copy above files as below

u01/perm/proj/sales/john/**.csv** files
u01/perm/proj/sales/mike/**.txt, .csv** files
u01/perm/proj/sales/geebee/sale/**.csv** files

thank you.

Comment: Use `rsync`, you will be a lot happier than trying to do it by yourself in a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with rsync. If you wanted to just take .txt and .csv files from a source directory, you can copy only those files along with their associated directory structure to the target.

**For example:**

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*.csv" --include="*.txt"  --exclude="*" u01/temp/ u01/perm/
```

If you wanted to do the inverse and do something like copy all files except `.json` and `.xlsx`, you would use `--exclude` in your command invocation like so:

```
rsync -avz --exclude="*.json" --exclude="*.xls" --exclude="*.xlsx" u01/temp/ u01/perm/
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                                                                                                           can you please share rsync code to copy all type files except '.JSON' and 'Excel' format files to /u01/perm path including folders.

Comment: @cg369 If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).